# overriding the equals method in java

Tags: java

"Let’s implement the equals method for a Stamp class.
You need to override the equals method of the Object class.
Now you have a slight problem.
The Object class knows nothing about stamps, so
it declares the otherObject
parameter variable of the equals method to have the type
Object. When overriding the method, you are not allowed to change the type of the parameter variable."

Here, it says that we are not allowed to change type of the parameter variable.
However, when I use the below code, it gives me the correct result.

```
public class Stamps
{
  private String color;
  private int value;

  public Stamps(String color, int value)
  {
    this.color=color;
    this.value=value;
  }

    public boolean equals(Stamps other)
    {
       return color.equals(other.color)
            && value== other.value;
    }
}


public class Main
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
          Stamps stamp1 = new Stamps("red",10);
          Stamps stamp2 = new Stamps("green",10);

        System.out.println(stamp1.equals(stamp2));       
     }
}
```

Here, I'm not overriding the equals() method inherited from Object class since parameter types are different. So, instead of using my code, shouldn't it use the one inherited from Object class ?

Comment: The most specific signature is chosen, and that is your overload.

Comment: Put an `@Override` annotation on your `equals` method and see what happens. You're defining your own function that so happens to have the same name as `Object#equals`, but you're not overriding it.

Comment: It gives you the correct result for your particular code, but for code that deals with arbitrary objects like maps and sets, it won't work (and it'll be very hard to debug why).

Comment: Change the second statement to `Object stamp2 = new Stamps("red",10)` and try running it again.

Comment: Try `Object obj3 = new Stamps("red",10);`. Note that the variable is of type `Object`. Also note that the object assigned to it should be equal to `stamp1`. Try that: try `obj3.equals(stamp1)` and also `stamp1.equals(obj3)`. I expect false both times. If I get that, you haven’t got the correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write a method invocation expression in Java, [a complex set of rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) is followed to determine which method will be invoked.

Basically, the compiler will search for the most specific method that it can find which matches the types of the parameters you are trying to pass in.

The important thing about these rules is that *they make no special provision for methods in `Object`*, or any other class. The methods in `Object` are treated exactly the same as any method you define yourself.

So, if you are trying to invoke an `equals` method on an instance of class `Stamps`, passing in a single instance of `Stamps` as a parameter, it will find your method:

```
boolean equals(Stamps other)
```

This is more specific than the one on `Object`:

```
boolean equals(Object other)
```

("More specific" is informally defined in the spec thus: any parameter you can pass to a "more specific" method can also be passed to a "less specific" method, but not vice versa).

so the Java compiler will choose to invoke the `equals(Stamps)` method.

However, if you were to change either the first or second (or both) declarations of the variables to be of `Object` type:

```
Object stamp1 = new Stamps("red",10);
```

then the `equals(Stamps)` method would not be invoked:

- For `Object stamp1`, this would be because Java would search the `Object` type for matching methods. Since only `equals(Object)` exists on `Object`, this is the only possible on to invoke.
- For `Object stamp2`, this would be because the parameter type of `equals(Stamps)` would not match, so the only possible method to invoke would be `equals(Object)`.

Answer (score 2):

The `java.lang.Object` equals method takes an `Object` parameter.  You aren't overriding it if you make it take a `Stamp`.

Joshua Bloch tells you how to override equals *and* hashCode properly in Effective Java [chapter 3](http://fpl.cs.depaul.edu/jriely/ds2/extras/Chapter3.pdf).

Follow his recommendation rigorously.  Your posted code isn't correct.  You don't even attempt hashCode. They should be done in pairs.